# How to change fonts only opacity

Tags: css

Hi all I need only change  `fonts` opacity in  `css` is any way for this?
p.s. I need only change `fonts`

Comment: have you tried setting their colour like `color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need to do is set the alpha channel on the p tag. So for example:

```
p { color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3); }
```

Comment: Like my question please :)

Answer (score 3):

Use RGB instead of Hexadecimal for the colour of your text, then add opacity to this like below. (this is for grey text with opacity)

```
p {
    color: rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.8);
}
```

Change the 0.8 depending on how much opacity you require, the lower the number the more opacity.

Answer (score -1):

Why dont You put that text inside special div with transparent background and then manipulate its opacity ?